# How do I create a Rails form that submits to a RESTful action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

With Rails 5, how do I create a form that submits to a RESTful action?

In my routes file I have:

```
  resources :people do
    collection do
      get 'image/:id', :to => "people#image", :as => 'image'
      get 'ranks', :to => "people#ranks", :as => 'ranks'
      get 'search/:search(.:format)', to: 'people#search'
    end
  end
```

So I'm wondering how to construct a form that submits to the "search" action.

I tried the following:

```
<%= form_tag(people_search_path) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

But this results in the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `people_search_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff2afc59168>:0x00007ff2afc50f68>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `rake routes`, you'll see that your search path has no name:

```
image_people GET    /people/image/:id(.:format)        people#image
ranks_people GET    /people/ranks(.:format)            people#ranks
             GET    /people/search/:search(.:format)   people#search
      people GET    /people(.:format)                  people#index
             POST   /people(.:format)                  people#create
  new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)              people#new
 edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format)         people#edit
      person GET    /people/:id(.:format)              people#show
             PATCH  /people/:id(.:format)              people#update
             PUT    /people/:id(.:format)              people#update
             DELETE /people/:id(.:format)              people#destroy
```

If, instead, you do:

```
resources :people do
  collection do
    get  'image/:id', :to => "people#image", :as => 'image'
    get  'ranks', :to => "people#ranks", :as => 'ranks'
    get  'search/:search(.:format)', to: 'people#search', as: :search
  end
end
```

You'll see your path now has a name:

```
  image_people GET    /people/image/:id(.:format)         people#image
  ranks_people GET    /people/ranks(.:format)             people#ranks
 search_people GET    /people/search/:search(.:format)    people#search
        people GET    /people(.:format)                   people#index
               POST   /people(.:format)                   people#create
    new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)               people#new
   edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format)          people#edit
        person GET    /people/:id(.:format)               people#show
               PATCH  /people/:id(.:format)               people#update
               PUT    /people/:id(.:format)               people#update
               DELETE /people/:id(.:format)               people#destroy
```

Which you can use as `search_people_path`.

BTW, I believe that `(.:format)` bit is unnecessary and you can simply do:

```
post 'search/:search', to: 'people#search', as: :search
```

If I were you, however, I would do:

```
resources :people do
  collection do
    get  'image/:id', :to => "people#image", :as => 'image'
    get  'ranks', :to => "people#ranks", :as => 'ranks'
    get  :search, to: 'people#search', as: :search
  end
end
```

Which will give you:

```
  image_people GET    /people/image/:id(.:format)         people#image
  ranks_people GET    /people/ranks(.:format)             people#ranks
 search_people GET    /people/search(.:format)            people#search
        people GET    /people(.:format)                   people#index
               POST   /people(.:format)                   people#create
    new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)               people#new
   edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format)          people#edit
        person GET    /people/:id(.:format)               people#show
               PATCH  /people/:id(.:format)               people#update
               PUT    /people/:id(.:format)               people#update
               DELETE /people/:id(.:format)               people#destroy
```

Then, I would update your form as Anees Muhammed suggests (I used `:terms` instead of `:search`):

```
<%= form_tag search_people_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :terms %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Then, when you submit, you should get something like:

```
Started GET "/people/search?terms=foo" for ::1 at 2018-01-29 13:49:40 -0800
Processing by People#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "terms"=>"foo", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

And you can access your terms by doing `params[:terms]`.

There is, BTW, *nothing* "non-RESTful" about this. It is, IMO, completely consistent [the Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for adding RESTful actions.

Comment: In order to get this to work, do I need to change my form to "<%= form_tag(search_people_path) do %>"?  I'm geussing the answer is no b/c when I do that and submit my form I get the error, "No route matches [POST] "/people/search/abc".

Comment: Updated to use the `POST` verb. Previously, you were using the `GET` verb and that's why you get the `"No route matches [POST] ..."` message.

Comment: Thanks but I woudl like to keep it as a "GET" submit, if only so that people can email the link around.  I added a ", method: :get" into my form tag, biut as my comment to the other answer revealed, when I submit my form, its tacking on a "&search=str" instead of submitting as a RESTful action (e.g. /search/str)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and why you're getting the behavior you're getting. But, IMO, what you're trying to do goes against convention. There *may* be a way, but I would suggest you take the more conventional approach of accessing your search terms by way of your query string, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Ok thx.  I would like to use convention as much as possible.  I'm still confused about why people use RESTful URLs like "/path/param_value" as opposed to "/path?param=param_value".

Comment: Updated answer. This approach *is* "RESTful" as indicated by the reference to the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `search_people_path` instead of `people_search_path`. But I don't think that change will take you to what you are trying to achieve. Since your route is 
`get 'search/:search(.:format)', to: 'people#search'`
 rails will expect you to provide a value for the keyword `:search` to build a url like `/people/search/yoursearchterm` with something like `search_people_path(yoursearchterm)`. For your functionality to work, change the form to

```
<%= form_tag search_people_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

and then in your controller

```
def search
  params[:search]
end
```

Also the routes to

```
get 'search', to: 'people#search'
```

**Updated**

Since you are trying to submit the form directly to a rest route like `search/:search`, I believe there is no direct rails way to achieve the same because that's how forms work. But if all you want is just a rest route like `yourwebsite.com/search/yoursearchterm` when you submit the form, there are some workarounds to achieve this. Either you have to write a piece of `js` on submitting the form and forward the request to your route with the input value or you can perform a redirect in the controller to the route, like this.
Routes:

```
resources :people do
    collection do
      get 'search', to: 'people#search_people'
      get 'search/:search', to: 'people#search'
    end
  end
```

So, first the form will be submitted to `search_people` action and then redirect to search with params. In controller

```
def search_people
    redirect_to search_people_path(params[:search])
end
```

This will then give you a url `yoursite.com/people/search/searchterm` and then in your `search` action, you can use the search params.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THanks but this isn't quite working.  When I change things to your suggestion and type in "spo" into my search form, it submits to the URL, "http://localhost:3000/people/search/sss?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=spo&commit=Search".  On the back-end, "sss" is still getting picked up as the value of the search parameter instead of "spo," which I typed into my textbox.

Comment: Hi, @Natalia. I've updated the answer. Please let me know if there is anything in this that I can help you with. Thanks